# How to use Group By and Having together

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following data set

```
id  name   units  release_date
1   salil   1    2012-04-02
2   salil   2    2012-03-21
3   salil   3    2012-04-02
4   salil   4    2012-03-02
5   salil   5    2012-04-02
6   xyz     1    2012-04-01
7   xyz     2    2012-03-30
8   xyz     3    2012-03-30
9   xyz     4    2012-04-01
```

I want the SUM of an unit for Maximum date for each name. something like follwing

```
name  units     Max(release_date)
salil  9          2012-04-02
xyz    5          2012-04-01
```

I try following but it is not working

```
SELECT name, MAX(release_date) as date, sum(units) as units FROM reports

 GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Here 'date' is a keyword in SQL, so won't use it as field name. Change it and try again

Comment: `artist_name` is not in your defined data set.

Comment: @ben,@RedFilter :- Its just typo.....i edited it though

Comment: What was the error message, or which data set did you get?

Comment: it is not giving me an error but it is giving me total sum instead of sum for that particular period

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
    SELECT name, sum(units) as units 
    FROM reports as r
    LEFT JOIN (select max(date) as maxdate from reports group by name ) as mr
    ON r.date=mr.maxdate
    WHERE artist_name='Pacer1'  GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: No this is giving me only one record i want for all the names

Comment: I am doubt full about artist_name='Pacer1'  why you used this in your query in your post ? might be due to this it's giving single name . Please remove it if no need